# jupyter-notebook output for loop not showing

Tags: jupyter-notebook, hachoir-parser

When i run my Jupyter-notebook with python2.7 and try to print items (of a list) using a for-loop it just won't output the print statement after importing the following packages:

```
import sys
import os
from hachoir_core.cmd_line import unicodeFilename
from hachoir_metadata import extractMetadata
from hachoir_parser import createParser
from hachoir_core.i18n import getTerminalCharset
from hachoir_core.tools import makePrintable
import pandas as pd
```

example code:

```
items = [1, 3, 0, 4, 1]
for item in items:
   print (item)
```

output is blank.

When I use the exact same code before importing, it does show.

Looks like hachoir imports are the problem, whenever I import anything containing it, the output stops showing.

Comment: It looks like hachoir is doing something peculiar with stdout: https://bitbucket.org/haypo/fusil/issues/1/hachoir-metadata-and-ipython

Comment: yea it does! I tried editing the **hachoir_core_i18n.py** file as described in the link you provided; changing
   **'unicode(translate(text), charset)'** 
to 
   **'unicode(translate(text), (charset if charset else sys.getdefaultencoding()))'**

that didn't change the output of the Jupyter-notebook though

Comment: Also, in the solution suggested the line on which the code should be changed  differs from the hachoir_core_i18n.py file i have. (148 instead of 144), maybe due to an updated hachoir version

Comment: I think you need to do the `from hachoir_core import config; config.unicode_stdout = False` step described in that link.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much Thomas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer: The `hachoir_metadata` module appears to do something odd with stdout which breaks IPython: [Bug report](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/fusil/issues/1/hachoir-metadata-and-ipython).

As described in that link, you need to add the following code *before* importing `hachoir_metadata`:

```
from hachoir_core import config
config.unicode_stdout = False
```